# Pandas: Cannot subtract date-time objects (timedelta, datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, timedelta

Here is the setup:

```
Python 3.9.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 21 2021, 05:00:30)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({
                      'user_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                      'created_at': [
                              '2017-01-01 10:10:15',
                              '2017-01-01 11:11:11',
                              '2017-01-01 12:12:12',
                              '2017-01-01 10:10:20',
                              '2017-01-01 10:10:34',
                              '2017-01-01 11:11:21'],
                      'transaction_value': [10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 50]
                      })

# convert string to datetime obj
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])


# convert other columns to numeric
cols = df.columns.drop('created_at')

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# creating lag1 and lag2
df['lag1'] = (
        df.sort_values(by=['created_at'], ascending=True)['created_at']
        .shift(periods=1, axis=0).fillna(0)
        )

df['lag2'] = (
        df.sort_values(by=['created_at'], ascending=True)['created_at']
        .shift(periods=-1, axis=0).fillna(0)
        )

# 0's to NaN
df = df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=False)

# convert to datetime
cols = [col for col in df if col.startswith('lag')]

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
```

```
Out[62]:
   user_id          created_at  transaction_value                lag1                lag2
0        1 2017-01-01 10:10:15                 10                 NaT                 NaT
1        2 2017-01-01 11:11:11                 20 2017-01-01 10:10:34 2017-01-01 10:10:34
2        3 2017-01-01 12:12:12                 10 2017-01-01 11:11:21 2017-01-01 11:11:21
3        4 2017-01-01 10:10:20                 30 2017-01-01 10:10:15 2017-01-01 10:10:15
4        5 2017-01-01 10:10:34                 40 2017-01-01 10:10:20 2017-01-01 10:10:20
5        6 2017-01-01 11:11:21                 50 2017-01-01 11:11:11 2017-01-01 11:11:11
```

```
In [63]: df.dtypes
Out[63]:
user_id                       int64
created_at           datetime64[ns]
transaction_value             int64
lag1                 datetime64[ns]
lag2                 datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I want the difference between all of the timestamp columns (results in seconds).

Here are the many things I have tried:

Attempt #1:

```
def x(a,b):
    return timedelta(a - b).total_seconds()

df.apply(lambda f: x(f['created_at'],f['lag1']), axis=1)

TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: NaTType

In [69]:
```

Okay, attempt #2:

```
pd.Timedelta(df['lag1'].difference(df['lag2']))

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'difference'
```

Okay... attempt #3:

```
pd.Timedelta(df['lag1'].subtract(df['lag2']).to_seconds())

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_seconds'
```

Now I'm just throwing stuff around and seeing what will stick, since this doesn't make any sense to me:

```
df['lag1'].subtract(df['lag2']).to_timedelta64

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_timedelta64'
```

```
t1 = df['lag1']
t2 = df['lag2']

pd.Timedelta(t2 - t1).seconds

ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible, not Series
```

I should not have to write a paragraph of code to get the difference between two datetimes

- pandas = 1.2.3 (conda-forge)
- numpy = 1.20.2 (conda-forge)
- datetime = 4.3 (pypi_0)

Machine I am on:

MacBook Air M1 2020 16GB RAM (macOS Big Sur Version 11.2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both columns are pandas `Timestamp`, you can do this:

```py
def x(a, b):
    return (a - b).total_seconds()
    
df.apply(lambda f: x(f['created_at'],f['lag1']), axis=1)
```

I don't know what you want to do in `NaT` cases (this function returns `NaN` for that), but you can easily change that.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution. I don't know why I didn't try that. I think I was getting caught up in the details. For example, not sure how `total_seconds()` works from the `datetime` library since the documentation for that function says it works on `timedelta` objects? Is the diff between two pandas `Timestamp` objects equivalent to a `datetime` `timedelta` object? Not sure I get _why_ this works, but I'll take it.  `NaN` for the missing datetime differences is exactly what I want.

Comment: Great @Cameron! Remember to mark as answered if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have not touched `NaT values`, please feel free to fill them with 0 or other values, if required.

We can use [pd.timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) along with `dt` accessor and then apply `total_seconds` method.
If the output is required as `int type` then add `.astype(int)` at the end of code.

**Code**

```
df['lag_diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.lag1 - df.lag2, unit='s').dt.total_seconds()
```

**Input from provided setup**

```
user_id created_at  transaction_value   lag1    lag2
0   1   2017-01-01 10:10:15 10  NaT            2017-01-01 10:10:20
1   2   2017-01-01 11:11:11 20  2017-01-01 10:10:34 2017-01-01 11:11:21
2   3   2017-01-01 12:12:12 10  2017-01-01 11:11:21 NaT
3   4   2017-01-01 10:10:20 30  2017-01-01 10:10:15 2017-01-01 10:10:34
4   5   2017-01-01 10:10:34 40  2017-01-01 10:10:20 2017-01-01 11:11:11
5   6   2017-01-01 11:11:21 50  2017-01-01 11:11:11 2017-01-01 12:12:12
```

**Output Subset of cols**

```
    lag1                lag2                lag_diff
0   NaT                 2017-01-01 10:10:20   NaN
1   2017-01-01 10:10:34 2017-01-01 11:11:21 -3647.0
2   2017-01-01 11:11:21 NaT                 NaN
3   2017-01-01 10:10:15 2017-01-01 10:10:34 -19.0
4   2017-01-01 10:10:20 2017-01-01 11:11:11 -3651.0
5   2017-01-01 11:11:11 2017-01-01 12:12:12 -3661.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Okay, this makes perfect sense to me based on what I know about `timedelta`, which was evidently very little to begin with. I like this solution a lot and can confirm that this works.